# Unable to correct magento product and category urls

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am using magento 1.7. magento product urls like `http://example.com/men/silver-cufflinks` then i want to remove `men` from url. i have commented following code in url.php

```
// if (null === $parentPath) {
       // $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
   // }
  //  elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
        $parentPath = '';
   // }
```

then empty core_url_rewrite table then clear cache and reindex all items and now i have urls like `http://example.com/catalog/category/view/s/women/id/181/`. i want to restore previous links please tell me how i can do this. i also again try after uncomment code which i have commented and again clear tabel and clear cache and then reindex all things but still i cannot fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you uncomment the code try to clean up url-rewrite tables manually and then run url-rewrites reindex again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ [Fixing URL Rewrites with Magento](http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento)

To remove the category path from product urls, you can do it from the magento admin

Go to Admin -> System -> Config -> Catalog

Then under 'Search Engine Optimizations' set 'Use Categories Path for Product URLs' to 'No'

[image]

Comment: Are you having this issue on a 'live' or a 'dev' site?

Comment: If you create a new product, will the url be seo friendly or /catalog/category/view/s/women..?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled URL rewrite?

> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization -> Use
>   Web Server Rewrites = Yes

Additionally you can also check:

> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

And this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to magento-catalog-click on the catalog in question, then going to the “url key” and changing it to what you want it to be. Make sure to change it in each store view and click “Save”.

Example:

```
Catalog
  → General Information
    → Name: Friends
    → Is active: Yes
    → URL key: friends
Store View: English French German
```

**These changes will rewrite all the subcategories.**